# built-in icons for most popular types of files

Tags: android

Whether there is in Android system a database of icons for the most popular types of files? Something like imageres.dll in Windows. Or any application should have its own icons for every file type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like iOS, Android tries to avoid "files" where possible, in terms of user experience. Hence, there is no "database of icons for the most popular types of files", because Android never shows icons for files, because Android rarely shows files at all.